# Accessing stdClass object the right way?

Tags: php, object, stdclass

I have an stdClass object that looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id1] => Fri Feb 22 00:02:15 +0000 2013
            [id2] => 21312
            [id3] => 13552412
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id1] => Fri Feb 22 00:02:15 +0000 2013
            [id2] => 21331
            [id3] => 13495842
        )
)
```

How do I access the IDs? I have found several similar questions, but none of them worked for me.
Lets assume the object is stored in `$myVar`.

I've tried `$myVar->0->id1`, `$myVar->id1`, `$myVar->[0]->id1`, `$myVar->['0']->id1`, `$myVar[0]->id1` but all without success.

Comment: Where did you get this object from? To me it looks like a casted array, so I ask myself, why it is casted to an object

Comment: @KingCrunch It's the REST API response from Twitter I think.

Comment: It's going to be curly braces `$myvar->{'0'}->id1`

Comment: If it's JSON, use the second parameter to json_decode. Else: http://array.include-once.org/?foreach=&assoc=&json=%7B%220%22%3A%7B%22id2%22%3A21242%7D%7D

Comment: You might also just do `$myvar = (array)$myvar;` to cast it back to an array and access as `$myvar[0]->id1`;

Comment: `$myvar = (array)$myvar;` totally did it for me :-) Post it as a response and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Like I assumed in the comments the structure doesn't look like it was ever intented to be treatened as an object. Instead of struggling around with the object, let [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json-decode) return an associative array in the first place instead

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data[0]['id1'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$myvar->{'0'}->id1`

or you can cast it as array first an then:

```
$arr = (array) $myobj;
$arr[0]->id1;
```